# View Based NSTableView with Sections

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I am looking for a way to create the iOS like sections in NSTableView (like in iTunes 11 - Attached).

As you can see in the screenshot, "Albums" is one section and "Songs" is second. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Try this - under complex cell tableviews https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want sections you basically have to roll your own (recognize that row x is supposed to be a section cell and provide a section view. [TwUI](https://github.com/github/twui) has TUITableView which enables this (and *massively* improves scroll performance, in my experience).

Comment: "recognize that row x is supposed to be a section cell and provide a section view" is exactly what I needed to move forward. I've tried to use TwUI before but I've kinda ran into some crash bugs with it.

Comment: There are some other solutions besides TwUI available, but I've found TwUI to be by far the smoothest.

Comment: I updated TWUI to allow for sticky headers - but there are cons with this library ( most notably you can't add nsview subviews). https://github.com/johndpope/osx-stickyheaders

Answer (score 22):

I see this is an old question, but the answer is to use a View based NSTableView then implement tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:.

This is code based on how I do it. It hasn't been compiled in Xcode.

```
-(NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    NSTableCellView *cell = nil;
        // get your row from your array of objects.
        // determine if it's a section heading or not.

    SomeClass *someObject = [self.myObjects objectAtIndex:row];

    if (someObject.isSectionHeading) {
        cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"HeaderCell" owner:self];
        cell.textField.objectValue = someObject.headingName;
    } else {
        cell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataCell" owner:self];
        cell.textField.objectValue = someObject.rowValue;
    }

    return cell;

}
```

And also tableView:isGroupRow will put a grey background on your section headings

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView isGroupRow:(NSInteger)row {
    BOOL isGroup = NO;
    // Choose some way to set isGroup to YES or NO depending on your records.
    return isGroup;
}
```

Make sure in Interface Builder you have set the identifiers for your NSTableCellViews to "HeaderCell" and "DataCell". Or use whatever names you want. As long as it matches your code. You can have as many of these cells as you want.

If you make a subclass of NSTableCellView then you can easily add your own text fields, checkboxes, images, etc. to the view and set their values accordingly.

Comment: May I add that you can also provide the height of the cell differently between the content cells and section cells by implementing `tableView:heightOfRow:` method. For the section cell, you can use the default height like this: `[tableview rowHeight]` and for the content cell you can use your own, like 70.0.

Comment: As far as I'm aware - this technique doesn't actually stick the header view at the top of view like the iphone does. I've only been able to create this effect using TWUI  github.com/johndpope/osx-stickyheaders

Comment: @johndpope Check out the property on NSTableView called `floatsGroupRows`

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good and simple tutorial showing how to implement a `NSTableView` with sections with sample code on github. Just watch it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjTwLa9mZEo) and in the video description there is a link to download the code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the proper way to deal with this these days is to implement the table view delegate method `tableView(rowViewForRow:)`. If you detect that the specified row is not a header, simply return nil. Otherwise, the process is similar to making a view for a specific table row and column. For example, if you store all your row data in a single array of `Any` called `tableRows`, and determine the difference between a header and an ordinary row by using different classes within that array, it might look something like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let headerNib = NSNib(nibNamed: "HeaderRow", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(headerNib, forIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "SectionHeader"))
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView? {
    guard let headerData = tableRows[row] as? SectionHeader else { return nil }
    let header = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "SectionHeader"), owner: nil) as? HeaderRow
    header?.titleLabel.stringValue = headerData.title
    return header
}
```

*Note that this only works if your table is view-based!*